# Mocking NSBundle in Swift TDD

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

Is it possible to mock an applications NSBundle to return predictable results during TDD?

For example:

I want to test that my application handles when a file is not saved to the NSBundle:

```
//Method to test
func getProfileImage() -> UIImage {
    if let profileImagePath = getProfilePhotoPath() {
        UIImage(contentsOfFile: profileImagePath)
    }
    return UIImage(named: "defaultProfileImage")
}

private func getProfilePhotoPath() -> String? {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("profileImage", ofType: "png")
}
```

Is it possible to mock the NSBundle.mainBundle() to return false for a pathForResource?

Answer (score 5):

As it stands, `NSBundle.mainBundle()` is a hard-coded dependency. What we'd like is the ability to specify *any* bundle, perhaps with mainBundle as the default. The answer is [Dependency Injection](https://qualitycoding.org/dependency-injection/). Let's use the preferred form of Constructor Injection, and take advantage of Swift's default parameters:

```
class ProfileImageGetter {
    private var bundle: NSBundle

    init(bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()) {
        self.bundle = bundle
    }

    func getProfileImage() -> UIImage {
        if let profileImagePath = getProfilePhotoPath() {
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: profileImagePath)!
        }
        return UIImage(named: "defaultProfileImage")!
    }

    private func getProfilePhotoPath() -> String? {
        return bundle.pathForResource("profileImage", ofType: "png")
    }
}
```

Now a test can instantiate a ProfileImageGetter and specify any bundle it likes. This could be the test bundle, or a fake.

Specifying the test bundle would allow you to have a situation where profileImage.png doesn't exist.

Specifying a fake would let you stub the result of calling `pathForResource()`.